# Получить значение текущего года

Tags: c#

Как получить значение текущего года ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Сначала нужно получить значение "сейчас" с помощью [DateTime.Now](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.datetime.now(v=vs.110).aspx)

А затем воспользоваться свойством [Year](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.datetime.year(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
var currentYear = DateTime.Now.Year;
```

Comment: Работает, спасибо !